# Why can't I see all textures in the 3D viewport?

Tags: materials

Rookie content creator here, but new to the forums. Been working with Blender for a little over a year now and only now have I encountered this issue where my textures in the Materials Viewport seem to mysteriously disappear and clip to where I can't see them all entirely and only in parts. Perhaps my finger slipped and turned on/off a setting, perhaps it's a bug, not entirely sure. Any feedback on how to fix this would be hugely appreciated!
[image]

Comment: Can you render it, do textures show up properly?

Comment: Yes and no. When I render it still showed the texture clipping like shown above, but when I powered up Blender this morning and looked at it there was seemingly no issue. Perhaps a visual bug when swapping between the Texture and Material tabs?